# Deleting duplicate nodes from a sorted linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to delete duplicate nodes from a sorted linked list. The code I used is -

```
Node* RemoveDuplicates(Node *head)
{
    struct Node *ptr = head;
    int var = ptr->data;

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        var = ptr->data;
        if(var == ptr->next->data)
        {
            ptr->next = ptr->next->next;

        else
            ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Forget the `free(ptr)` statement, other than that I guess everything is fine but the above code is not working.
Is there any problem in the logic as I saw a similar code online but with one additional pointer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "not working". Does it not compile? Get stuck? Crash? Produce the wrong result? Also see how to make a [mcve].

Comment: `struct Node *ptr = head;` if this is `c++` you don't need the `struct` here. Although that will not cause an error.

Comment: 1. what happens if head is null?

Comment: 2. what happens if ptr->next is null

Comment: ...why a manually implemented linked list in C++, where we have [`std::forward_list<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list), which would give us the ability to use the wonderful [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) (and iterators in general)...? Avoiding such issues as the above wholesale?

Comment: Not working i.e. is not giving any output and on online coding platform it is giving segementation fault.

Comment: In c++, prefer `new/delete` over `malloc/free`. Otherwise, if `Node` isn't POD, you will be in trouble. And you would generally want to use `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` instead `new/delete`.

Comment: "Not giving any output" is somewhat self-explanatory if the code you presented does not *do* any output. Check again what [mcve] means, please.

Comment: It is returning a pointer to the head which will further be used to print the output.

Comment: I took care of the head = NULL and ptr->next = NULL, in my alternative code but other than that is there anything else going wrong?

Comment: @LovVerma: Please check my first comment. Unless you have a *specific* need, you should use the standard library instead of "rolling your own". Others have debugged the snot out of those implementations so you don't have to...

Comment: You need to spend a little time debugging. Either start up your debugger and single step the program, or add some `printf` or `cout` statements that tell you what's happening. If you don't know how to use the debugger, this is the perfect time to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(var == ptr->next->data)
```

should be

```
if (ptr->next != NULL && var == ptr->next->data)
```

No guarantees in your code that the next pointer is not null,

Comment: when the next pointer is NULL, the ptr will be further set to NULL and the loop will end but that will happen in the end and that won't make the whole logic wrong that's what I think while giving a dry run.

Comment: @LovVerma Good job trying a dry run but you missed that when ptr->next is NULL then ptr->next->data is liable to crash the program.